# Cant put function as property javascript

Tags: javascript, function, properties

im trying to add a function to a property in nodejs, this is my main:

```
  const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const vpas = require('./auth');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var filename = "." + q.pathname;
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            return res.end("404 Not Found");
        }
        else {
            if (vpas.verify("asd", "asd")) {
                res.write(req.url);
            }
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write(data);
            return res.end();
        }

    });
}).listen(80);
```

whats important there is vpas.verify, that is the property throwing the error.

this is the auth module:

```
    var verifyPassword = function (name, password) {
    if (String(name) == String(password)) {
        return true;
    }
}


exports.auth = {
    verify: verifyPassword
};
```

I dont get why its throwing the error vpas.verify is not a function.
Please help me, i cant find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause its:

```
 vpas.auth.verify
```

`vpas` points to exports, and you set the `auth` property to it.